# Stripe PHP Best way to debug an SignatureVerificationException with Stripe-cli

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I created a webhook to get informations about checkout sessions :

```
 public function stripeWebhookCheckout(Request $request)
    {

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env("STRIPE_SECRET"));

        // You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
        $endpoint_secret = 'whsec_fVBkAmCztUTacQKZiyjmcq6QQrl8lKL1';

        $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
        $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
        $event = null;


        try {
            $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
                $payload,
                $sig_header,
                $endpoint_secret
            );
        } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
            // Invalid payload
            http_response_code(400);
            exit();
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
            // Invalid signature
            http_response_code(400);
            exit();
        }

        // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
        if ($event->type == 'checkout.session.completed') {
            $session = $event->data->object;

            // Fulfill the purchase...
            handle_checkout_session($session);

            $stripeSessionId = $session['id'];

            if (isset($stripeSessionId)) {
                $payment = Payment::where('stripe_sessioncheckout_id', '=', $stripeSessionId)->first();
                $payment->status = "success";
                $payment->data = $session;
                $payment->save();
            }


        }

        http_response_code(200);
    }
```

I use stripe-cli to test my webhook in local. And i have this kind of result

```
$ stripe listen --forward-to jvlb.test/api/stripe/webhook/checkout
> Ready! Your webhook signing secret is whsec_sc9Gh9A6zx3IOfBpH62F9DdPYIhSUYtw (^C to quit)
2019-11-28 16:19:06   --> charge.succeeded [evt_1FjsW5FIYszmshR0eGSB9GDo]
2019-11-28 16:19:06  <--  [400] GET https://jvlb.test/api/stripe/webhook/checkout [evt_1FjsW5FIYszmshR0eGSB9GDo]
```

To debug it i changes the http_response_code(400) and I realised it generate a SignatureVerificationException. 
My question is, how can i debug this ? Is it the $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'] who is wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution, if it can help people in the future :

I made a mistake in the way i use stripe-cli, i forgot "https://".

The good way is :

```
stripe listen --forward-to https://jvlb.test/api/stripe/webhook/checkout
```

And then i had few error of code to manage. I just used the tail command on my log file

```
tail -f storage/logs/laravel-2019-11-29.log
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I was sceptical that this would solve my issue, but it worked. Previously I'd added ":443" to my --forward-to URL with no scheme, but I was getting 400 errors with every request. Removing the port number and prefixing my URL with "https" worked, I now get 200 responses.